# how to make a imageview do a segue

Tags: objective-c, ios, gridview, uiimageview

I have a bunch of imageview generated in a gridview. But now I want that each imageview can do  a segue to another screen. Does anybody knows how I can do that? Here is the code of how I generated my imageview and put it into my grid.

```
UIImageView * myView = [[UIImageView  alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
        CGRect rect = myView.frame;
        rect.origin.x = xCurrent;
        rect.origin.y = yCurrent;
        myView.frame = rect;
        myView.tag = cellCounter;
        [gridContainerView addSubview:myView];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

        myView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [myView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Please help

Kind regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a tapGestureRecognizer. Add one of those to your image views and make the action call your segue method.

`UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];`

`UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mySequeMethod:)];`

`img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

`[img addGestureRecognizer:tap];`

Comment: I edited my code with the tap gesture but this is stil not working.

Comment: does your handleTap method get called?

Comment: I putted an NSLog in my handleTap method. But it doesn't show up.

Comment: check that user interaction is enabled on your gridContainerView

Comment: I did the following  myView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            gridContainerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 0):

A:

use a custom button instead of UIImageView, and set the image... and then segue with that button, (it looks the same)

---

B:

use a gesture recognizer to the view, and use a tap with one finger.

Comment: I edited my question with a tap gesture recognigzer but still not working.

Comment: Try use UIButton then, or... is your method mySequeMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture ? that's what the : stands for, a argument.